# in symfnoy2 is there any third party bundle which will allow to map the database column and excel/csv column while importing or exporting data

Tags: php, excel, symfony, csv, datagrid

In symfnoy2 is there any third party bundle which will allow to map the database column and excel/csv column as per users choice.

Also we should be able to import excel/csv and export data into excel/csv.

It should show data in data grid view before uploading it to database.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there is no 1 bundle that will do all of that, but there are bundles that would make good candidates for the main parts.

[DdeboerDataImportBundle](https://github.com/ddeboer/DdeboerDataImportBundle) is very good and very flexible to handle the actual imports.

[APYDataGridBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle) we use a great deal to display data in grids.  It has many features including built in filtering (and prefiltering via query string)

you would obviously need to tie these together if you wanted to display before flushing, but that would be doable but you would need to get your hands dirty in the import bundle.

Comment: Thank you for solution! but Is there any bundle to allow user to map columns of the excel / csv to database table fields ?

Comment: yes, you can use the DataImportBundle to do that.   When we used it, we created a crud that would allow the user to specify which csv column related to what field for import. EDIT: it will also write csv as well.

Comment: Hey Matt,
I am trying to install DdeboerDataImportBundle , but it gives error :
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception 

and one more :
[RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.